# Isoperimetric inequality using rearrangements

Tags: analysis, inequality, rearrangement-inequality

The Wikipedia post on "Symmetric decreasing rearrangements" says that "The Pólya–Szegő inequality yields, in the limit case, with $p=1$, the isoperimetric inequality". I tried to search the proof over internet but I couldn't find it. Anyone please provide a proof or a reference.

Comment: It does mean for a triangle? If so, by Karamata it's possible

Comment: It doesn't specify anything about the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 4.10 in the book Symmetrization in Analysis by
ALBERT BAERNSTEIN [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/symmetrization-in-analysis/9AE232062CC3EC6A585A3F2E3149D67D://)